# Unable to save values to Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, appdelegate

I am trying to store data to Core-Data in `AppDelegate` itself and then fetch that data from `ViewController`. For some reason, it is not getting saved in Core-Data. I have tried searching for this issue on the internet but did not get any specific solution. I have pasted the code below -

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func saveContext () {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    print(context)
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Msg", in: context)
    print(entity)
    let new = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
    print(new)
    print(getData.alert_message)
    new.setValue(getData.alert_message, forKey: "title")
    do {
        try context.save()
        print("save")
        print(new.value(forKey: "title"))
    } catch {
        let nserror = error as NSError
        fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
    }  
}
```

**Console Output**

[image]

Comment: Please provide your log details which you are printing.

Comment: It's not clear if you have an issue saving or fetching, the title says one thing but the text another.

Comment: Fetching the data is the later part, firstly I need to check whether it is getting stored in Core data or not.

Comment: @Khushbu I have provided the log screenshot

Comment: What is wrong with the code? According to the console output the record is saved. But why don't you use the generic API for `NSManagedObject` subclasses and dot notation

Comment: I have done the coding in AppDelegate file and in order to view the saved data of CoreData I am using a tool known as "DB Browser for SQLite" so there I am not able to view any data. I am confused whether the data has been saved or not.

Comment: @vadian How to use generic API for NSManagedObject?

Comment: `let new = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Msg", into: context) as! Msg` `new.title = getData.alert_message`

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong with this part of the code. What is your `PeristentContainer` creation code?

Comment: The issue got resolved! Thanks guys for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch record from the entity by `NSFetchRequest`

Try with below method, You just need to pass name of the entity as argument of the function.

```
func getAllRecordFromTableWhere(_ tableName: String) -> [NSManagedObject]? {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: tableName)
    do {
        return try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
    return nil
}
```

and call function like

```
if let arrayOfData = DBHelper.getAllRecordFromTableWhere("Msg") {
    print(arrayOfData)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Hear I have Set My Own Solution, Hope This help You


let contex = ((UIApplication.shared.delegate) as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

func SaveData()
 {
 let entity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Employee", into: contex);
        entity.setValue(txtname.text, forKey: "empname") // txtname.text is My TexField name 
        entity.setValue(txtadd.text, forKey: "empadd");
        do
        {
            try contex.save();
        }
        catch
        {

        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not giving values to all attributes of the entity so check that first.

try something like

new.setValue(msgdata, forKey: "msgdata")

//msgdata is what you want to save on Coredata entity

//try something like this

Comment: Check my code in the question I have tried it in the function itself.

Comment: new.setValue(getData.alert_message, forKey: "title")
give value to all attributes and check all attribute name should be same as declared in coredata.

https://github.com/Ashutos39/ContactBookDemo hope this will help you out.

Comment: Thank you for the link I will refer it if needed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was trying to update data saved in core data. but every time it was returning the old data ( not the updated version )

> Saved successfully message was being printed in console same as yours

Here are some simple steps that finally solved my problem

- fetch data with a `NSFetchRequest`
- save data into a temp variable
- delete old data from core data
- modify data from temp variable
- and finally save context

Here is my update data function

```
func updateUserData(_ userDetails: UserModel) {

    let request = UserDetails.fetchRequest() as NSFetchRequest<UserDetails>
    do {
        let result = try persistentContainer.viewContext.fetch(request)
        if let data = result.first?.userData as Data? {
            var loginModel = LoginModel(data: data)
            loginModel?.user = userDetails
            self.clearUserData() //deleting old data
            self.userLoginData = loginModel?.jsonData
        }
    }catch let error as NSError {
        debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
    }

}
```